# The view Kek.views.login didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django

Пытаюсь создать форму логина. Видимо плохо пытаюсь:(

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from .models import MyUser


class MyUserLoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ('username', 'password')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(MyUserLoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field_name, field in self.fields.items():
            field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, AbstractUser

class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect
from Kek.forms import MyUserLoginForm
from django.contrib import auth
from django.urls import reverse


def login(request):
    title = "Вход"

    login_form = MyUserLoginForm(data=request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST' and login_form.is_valid():
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user and user.is_active:
            auth.login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('https://simpleblog.com/posts/archive/')

        content = {'title': title, 'login_form': login_form}
        return render(request, 'templates/login/login.html', content)
```

login.html

```
{% extends 'templates/base/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block title %}
    Login
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="{% url 'AuthApp:login' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ login_form.as_p }}
        <br>
        <input class="form-control" type="submit" value="войти">
    </form>



{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
import Kek.views as kek

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', kek.login, name='login'),
]
```

Сама ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ошибка говорит, что ваша функция `login` во views.py ничего не возвращает, т.е. она даже первое условие (`if request.method == 'POST' and login_form.is_valid():`) не проходит, т.к. оно возвращает `False` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def login(request):
    title = "Вход"

    if request.method == 'POST':
        login_form = MyUserLoginForm(request.POST)
        if login_form.is_valid():
            username = login_form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = login_form.cleaned_data['password']

            user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user and user.is_active:
                auth.login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('https://simpleblog.com/posts/archive/')
    else:
        login_form = MyUserLoginForm()
    content = {'title': title, 'login_form': login_form}
    return render(request, 'templates/login/login.html', content)
```